# Rails: Multi-tenant app and dynamic routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, routes, multi-tenant

I've created a multi-tenant app using `apartment` and `devise` gem. Since, I'm using postgresql, `apartment` gem will create separate schema for each tenant. My database as a few tables, `user` table is in public namespace whereas `pages` table is in each tenant specific schema. I'm able to login to each tenant separately and can create separate records for pages table of each tenant.

Now, I want these pages to be accessible in a format like this `tenant1.example.com/page-slug-here` for this I've following rule in my `routes.rb` file:

```
Page.where.not(slug: nil).all.each do |page|
  get "/#{page.slug}", controller: "pages", action: "show", id: page.id
end
```

These routing rules were working fine when the app was single-tenant but in multi-tenancy it's not working and is throwing "no route matches" error.

My guess here is that the database call in above routing rule is looking in `public` schema instead of tenant specific schema. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. The routing code pasted above was copied from a tutorial but it seems the `apartment` gem doesn't work well with the ActiveRecord native queries in `routes.rb` file. Apparently, the `Page.where()...` call was being mapped to `public` tenant instead of requested tenant at the point of resolving of routes so I've moved the database query from router to controller and in controller the tenant shift was being applied correctly.

I've simplified my routing rule as follows and now it is working and I can find appropriate page by slug in my controller:

```
get '/:slug' => 'pages#show'
```